# Having trouble with the getSource method on buttons

Tags: java, swing, methods, awt, actionlistener

I have a GUI with 2 JButtons and I would like to know which one is firing an event by using the getSource method. I looked all over Google for a solution to my problem but couldn't find one, here's my code:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    if (event.getSource() == btn1){
        System.out.println("this should work");
    }else if (event.getSource() == btn2){
        System.out.println("this should work as well");
    }
```

but it doesn't print anything when I press either button, I also tried this:

```
 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
     if ((JButton)event.getSource() == btn1){
         System.out.println("this should work");
     }else if ((JButton)event.getSource() == btn2){
         System.out.println("this should work as well");
    }
```

but that didn't work either.

Could someone please tell me what's wrong?

Comment: I don't know if it makes a difference in this case, but, have you tried `equals()` instead of `==`?

Comment: try System.out.println(event.getSource) to check what source is

Comment: Set a breakpoint and manually inspect the value that `event.getSource()` returns.

Comment: Who knows if you added the ActionListener to the buttons or even if you defined the variables btn1 and btn2 properly. Don't make us guess. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You may be shadowing your variables, declaring `btn1` and `btn2` as instance variables at the class level, but redclaring them when you build the ui.  Would need to see a working example for we could be sure

Comment: You should never compare objects with the `==` operator as that would try to match their *reference* pointers which might no doubt be different. Use the `equals` method.

Comment: Its very simple. As @MadProgrammer has also pointed out. Your `btn1` and `btn2` don't point to same button instances in the heap. Means they are not same. This will not print anything because even your `else` has condition.

Comment: Have you actually added the `actionlistener` to these `buttons`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reccomend to use 2 different actionListener to ur buttons, so u dont have to do (if else)

```
btn.addActionListener(new MyActionListener1());
btn2.addActionListener(new MyActionListener2());
```

but if u want to test ur problem i recommend u to declare ur variables btn1 and btn2
as final.

```
final JButton btn1= new JButton();
final JButton btn2= new JButton();
```

so u can ensure that ur variable is allways "pointing" to the same position. Another thing u can do is setting the property name to the buttons so u can do the equals with that property

```
btn1.setName("name");
```

and in the actionListener

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    if ( btn1.getName().equals( ( (Component)event.getSource() ).getName()){
        System.out.println("this should work");
      ....
```

Comment: Thanks for all your guys help, appreciate it. I'm rather new to Java and don't have much experience

Answer (score 0):

***Issue*** with your code:

Your `btn1` and `btn2` don't point to same button instances in the heap. Means they are not same. This will not print anything because even your `else` has same condition.

**Solution**:

***Use text*** on the button to detect what button was pressed:

```
((JButton)event.getSource()).getText().equals("mybutton")
```

Comment: its not working for me..tried the same things with single action listener.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.
Later I realized I was initializing the same button 2 times.

In the class I used

**Button b1,b2;**

And later in the constructor's initializing method
I wrote

```
Button b1=new Button();
Button b2=new Button();
```

That's wrong because in this way b1 and b2 will be pointed towards a new address.

The correct way to write in the constructor's initializing method is:

```
b1=new Button();
b2=new Button();
```

In this way the variable will hold the object of the new button class and the address won't be changed.

Hope this helps.